# Ansible EC2 Dynamic Library Boto Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto

I'm trying to run ansible with the ec2.py inventory file to make some updates on a fleet of servers.  But I keep receiving the error message:

`ERROR! Attempted to execute "inventories/ec2.py" as inventory script: Inventory script (inventories/ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Sites/admin/ansible/inventories/ec2.py", line 130, in <module>
    from boto import elasticache
ImportError: cannot import name elasticache`

I have tried to reinstall both ansible via homebrew and boto via pip but to no avail.  Looking for any direction on how I can solve this issue.

My setup:

- Mac OSX 10.11.6
- Python 2.7.13
- Ansible 2.3.0.0
- boto 2.46.1

Answer (score 0):

So the issue lies in where boto was installed.  Boto had been installed with the root user and not my user. To resolve this issue run:

`pip install --user boto`